# Incremental Loading using Attunity Connector

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, etl, attunity

I have been trying to do incremental loading using Attunity connector. Below is the  package I am using. But its giving out errors. Can some one guide me on how I can proceed to get the latest records. Oracle Source is getting the latest updated records and Oracle Source is getting all the records. Also Do you think it will be slow as Oracle Source will be querying the whole table evenrytime I run the package. Is there any other way around?

[image]

Comment: There is too less information in the question for us to actually help you :(  . Your conditional split and OLE DB Command both have 1/multiple errors in them. without the error messages, how do you expect answers ? you should post the error messages as well. 

Also for the performance part, its always advisable to only fetch the changed records via SSIS. if you pull whole table data again and again, it will definitely be very slow, not sure if that makes much sense. It also depends on what kind of data you are pulling from those tables, can't suggest anything without that information

Comment: I have actually sorted out the errors. some how all the errors were because of the time formatting. I had to update hours HH to HH24. And it solved the issue. But the PERFORMANCE ISSUE is there as its loading the complete table in Oracle source1 . Can you suggest an alternative??????

Comment: without looking at your data, its really difficult to suggest an approach. Is it transaction data ? If yes, you can try with the getting only new data. Approach could be.. save a field in some table with `last_run_time` value, and in the oracle queries only pull data which has been created after the last_run_time. After your data flow tasks run, update the last_run_time with the current time. So everytime you run it, you will only get the changed data

Comment: Thanks Sudipta. I am storing the last run date time of the package and I have an update time field in the source tables. So I am getting all the fields(changed data) added/inserted after update date. But I need to compare it with the old data to know what is new and what is updated and what was removed. How do I do the comparison with the existing data in the target database? I am trying to search for an alternative to lookup as lookup doesn't work with attunity..

Comment: create a variable `last_run_time` in your package, create a sql task and map the variable to the `last_run_time` in the database. then in your dataflow task, use this variable to only fetch the changed data. Put this changed data in a staging table. Have another SQL task to do a Merge or Insert from staging to Base table.

Comment: bring only the changed data to the staging table and then merge staging with base table :)

Comment: Thats where the problem is. How should I be doing that? Should I be using lookup after getting them to staging.. is there a direct way as well without loading the data into staging?? coz anyways if i am not taking it to staging and directly loading it. The process is the same

Comment: it will not work without a staging table. How will you use Merge without a staging table.

Comment: I am connecting directly to the target database. So before I insert the new rows, i want to check if they are updates/deletes/inserts. and then apply that on the target database accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177989/discussion-between-sudipta-mondal-and-nancyk).